# What are the defaults for the "user rights assignment" in an AD environment?

Tags: active-directory

In a non-domain environment, gpedit.msc lets me associate various "user rights" (like "create a pagefile" or "create permanent shared objects") with users or accounts. This is in Computer Configuration | Windows Settings | Security Settings | Local Policies | User Rights Assignment.

Where exactly do I do this in AD? (Please don't just say e.g. "Group Policy Management Console". I've looked at all of the tools I can find, especially in GPMC, and I can't see it. I need either very explicit directions or screen snaps.

ADDED: Ok, I think I get it. You create a new GPO, click Edit, and this gets you to the Group Policy Management *Editor* where I find the familiar path. Then I link my new GPO to the domain or the OU or whatever where I want it to apply.

But I still have a question: none of the rights in the editor come pre-set to anything. Well, that makes sense because it's a brand new GPO. But is there any way to know what the defaults are, defaults that my new GPO will override? For example, what rights do members of the "Domain Admins" group get, by default?

Comment: If the downvoter would like to explain the reason for the downvote, I'd love to read it. I've been looking for this answer for over an hour so "did not do any research" is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The defaults are documented in:

Group Policy Settings Reference Spreadsheet
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56946

On the Security tab. Covers all versions of Windows. (I don't believe it has been updated for 1809 yet).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're asking.

If you're asking for User Rights Assignment on a single computer, look for Local Security Policy.

If you're asking for User Rights Assignment as a group policy, well, it shows up just fine in my console.  Are you using [RSAT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520) (Remote Server Administration Tools)?  I'm using the RSAT available for Windows 10.  Older versions of RSAT (or the version on the domain controller) may be missing some options.

[image]

Comment: Yeah... I finally realized (after asking the first form of the question) that you can only see them when you open the Editor. It's surprising to me though that the Default Domain Policy comes with everything "Not defined" and yet the defaults are certainly being applied. Thanks!